# Why the popup script send more message to content script, when the popup is reopened?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have firefox webextension. In the popup.html I have a button and by clicking it, popup.js send message to content.js. Content.js recieve message and make console.log with text "Message from popup". If I click the button again, the action is repeated. Problem is when I click away from popup and open popup again and click the button again, because content.js recieve two message from popup.js and make two console.log. If I repeat it again, content.js recive three message, and so on.
How many times do I reopen the popup, as many times as the message is sent.

I think the problem is somewhere in popup.js, but I can't figure out.

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Extension",
    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "Firefox extension",

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "<all_urls>",
        "tabs"
    ],

    "browser_action": {
       "default_title": "Script",
       "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="action">Start</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
browser.tabs.executeScript({file: "content.js"})
.then(listenForClicks)

function listenForClicks() { 
  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("action")) {
      browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true})
        .then(send)
    }
    function send(tabs) { 
      browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
          command: "message"
          });
      }
  });
}
```

content.js:

```
function handleMessage(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.command === "message"){
      console.log("Message from popup");
    }
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);
```

Expected result is that one click of button causes make one console.log. Even thought the popup was reopened multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listeners are not removed immediately after the popup is closed. The Garbage Collector takes some time to remove it.

If you are using Firefox 50+ you can set the `once` in [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for the listener so the listener is removed after the first time.

For older browsers you can manually remove the listener with `document.removeEventListener()`.

Now, if you want the content to only receive ONE message, then you can remove the listener after the first time e.g:

**Update after comments**

popup.js:

```
// add event listener for the button (not the whole pop-up), to run ONCE only
document.querySelector('button.action').addEventListener('click', listener, {once: true}); // FF50+, Ch55+

async function listener() {

  await browser.tabs.executeScript({file: 'content.js'});
  const tabs = await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true});
  browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {command: 'message'});
}
```

content.js:

```
// add listener only if it wasnt done before
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('runOnce')) {

  // keep track of previous attempts in sessionStorage
  sessionStorage.setItem('runOnce', 'true');      
  browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);
}

function handleMessage(request, sender, sendResponse) {

  if(request.command === 'message'){
    console.log("Message from popup");

    // remove listern after the first run
    browser.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(handleMessage);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a solution to my problem. This will do that when I open the popup and I will click the button a few times, only one message will be sent. But it not solve the problem that when I close popup and open popup again, two message will be sent after clicking the button.

Problem example: I open and close the popup five times without clicking the button. Now, I open the sixth popup and click the button. Popup.js will send six messages instead of one.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works almost perfectly. It works when I open the popup, click the button and close popup. I can repeat these steps and it will work correctly. When I reopen popup without a clicking the button, then open the popup again and click the button, so it still works correctly.  
But if I reopen popup multiple times without clicks, it will send more messages when I click button again.  
Maybe have to remove the Listener from popup.js. I tried it, but without success.  
Do you have any ideas on how to solve this? @erosman

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.